# how to migrate a react-native-vanilla project to expo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native, expo

right now, I have a React-native project which I created with the vanilla CLI.

I just heard of expo, and I wanted to use it, but it seems I must create my project on it first.

is there a way to migrate a react-native-vanilla project to expo?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have `exp` installed, you can run `exp convert` in your project directory. Note that this process won't check whether you have any native modules in your project, and if you do you'll likely have some issues.

As of this writing, there's one notable bug in this process where it may leave your project with both an `exp.json` file and an `app.json` file, which need to be manually merged.